# How to Synchronize local database with server database? (not talking about replication)

Tags: php, mysql, database

**Scenario:**
I Created a POS (point of sale) system using mysql database. I am managing all shops data in one database. All operation was on server before but now the requirement is changed and i want to make it local too. The challenge i face is Duplicate entry for key primary

**For example:** 
The system is used by two shop. If one shop added record where id=1 in item table in his local database and the second shop also added record where id = 1 in same table in his local database. Now when i send both data to my server database, it will give me error on Duplicate entry for key primary.

**Conclusion:**
I am not using MYSQL replication because it not suit my database structure so what will be the best solution for this issue?

Comment: Since it is not a replication you can 
 set one local system of odd pks and another shop even pks 
 by changing a variable which is mentioned in the docs 
 refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html

Comment: not getting your point. could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Have a look on the document shared above on the topics `auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset` or have a look at federated engine but it has its limitations  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-usagenotes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in many ways:

1. You should not sync the primary key as well from the local to remote, rather you can have some `order ID` (`SHOPID_SOMERANDOM-NUMBER`) which will be `unique` for shops .
2. Otherwise you can keep a `composite` key as `primary key` like `Autoincrement_ID+SHOP_ID` so that while `syncing` this will never be duplicate.

This `shop_ID` should be generated from the server at the time of installation and should not be duplicate.

Comment: I have more than 50 tables so i have to do it in every table then? Like taking composite key in every table.

Comment: @AbdulSamadHassan probably yes. This is something you have to decide at the time of design